# Why is the hash table of HashMap marked as transient although the class is serializable

Tags: java, serialization, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I was looking at the source of [HashMap](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm).

A `HashMap` `implements Serializable`.

Ok this is so that it can be peristed/transmitted as an object.

But I see that the hashtable itself is marked as `transient`.

I don't get this.If you mark it as transient, doesn't this mean that it should **not** be serialized?

But all the data are in the table.So why is it `transient`?

Perhaps I am confused on how `Serializable` works?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`HashMap` uses `writeObject` and `readObject` to implement custom serialization rather than just letting its field be serialized normally. It writes the number of buckets, the total size and each of the entries to the stream and rebuilds itself from those fields when deserialized. As tzaman says, the table itself is unnecessary in the serial form, so it's not serialized to save space.

You can read more about those methods and some other methods of doing custom serialization (`writeReplace` and `readResolve`) in the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) javadoc.

Comment: I see this methods.I was wondering why does it do that way?Is there a reason?

Comment: The hash code of objects may change between runs of the program -- for example, if hashCode() uses the default Object implementation -- so the hash table has to be rebuilt during deserialization.

Answer (score 13):

The `transient` keyword indicates that a field shouldn't be included in the serialized representation of a class. The `Entry[]` table of a `HashMap` is simply an acceleration structure - it allows for fast lookup of the stored entries.
The entire table itself doesn't need to be serialized, just the entries it contains, since the table can be rebuilt again when deserializing from the list of entries.

Comment: Is this for size or speed?Because in deserialization you end up with a table of the same size anyway.

Comment: Size. The `Entry` table is larger than the list of keys.